# Unpack an array to the stack at runtime

Tags: arrays, stack, factor-lang

I have an array:

```
{ 1 2 3 4 }
```

I want to push its contents to the stack.

I tried:

```
(sc) { 1 2 3 4 } dup length firstn
1
2
3
4
```

Great!

Inside a word, though:

```
: explode ( a -- * ) dup length firstn ; inline
```

Throws an error `Cannot apply “firstn” to a run-time computed value`, because `firstn` calls `call` and

> Words which call an input parameter must be declared inline so that a caller which passes in a literal quotation can have a static stack effect.

... and because of `call`
's semantics it's hard to compute quotations at runtime.

There *must* be a way to accomplish this. What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Björn Lindqvist said, Factor won't let you do that<sup>1</sup>, but there are some workarounds.

The most direct way is perhaps using a [vector as a stack](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-sequences-stacks.html):

```
: explode ( v s -- v ) dupd [ swap push ] with each ;
V{ } "somestring" explode
==> V{ 115 111 109 101 115 116 114 105 110 103 }
```

Of course, this means redesigning all related functions to work with this.

Maybe better than vectors, there are also [string buffers](http://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-sbufs.html), that can behave like a stack too.

```
"somestring" >sbuf
==> SBUF" somestring"
"-abcd" [ over push ] each
==> "somestring-abcd"
```

(Alternatively `SBUF" somesbuf"`)

If you need to keep working with the content as if it were the input to some other words passed on the stack, you can use `with-datastack`:

```
"somestring-abcd" [ 5 ndrop 3dup ] with-datastack >string
==> "somestringing"
```

But think of this as if it where a regular non-stack-based language. Each word takes a fixed number of parameters and outputs a fixed number of results.

[1]. There must be some metaprogramming ways to do this. I don't imagine there's an easy practical way, though.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to write such a word. If you think you need a word like that, you must rethink how you approach the problem.